# Не получается Attach to proceess VS2015 к удалённой машине когда загружен solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, отладка

### Наблюдаю странный баг:

- Когда в VS2015 solution  не загружен делаю debug>attach to process .В Qualifier  вбиваю адресс  целевой машины (например 192.168.32.12:4020) нормально загружается список процессов на целевой машине , нормально дебагер  подрубается к нужном w3wp.exe процессу.
- Если загружен проект , студия не хочет подключаться к удалённому  отладчику а падает с ошибкой  :

  ---

  Microsoft Visual Studio

  ---

  Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named      '192.168.32.12'.  Неверная попытка доступа к адресу памяти.

  ---

  ОК   Справка

  ---

На целевой  машине поставлен нужной версии VS remote debuger  конгруэнтный версии студии  :(Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3)
Студия  иноземная стоит, а вот сообщение об ошибке наполовину на иноземном наполовину на русском ...
никто не знает как лечится?

Answer (score 1):

Помогло изменение порта подключения на 41022